# RGB, how to generate matching colors palette?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am developing an application where I have to play around with some RGB colors. Actually, I have RGB and its HEX/HSV equivalent.

Now, I am trying to dynamically generate matching colors for a selected color, lets say 'Red', then I would like to generates 5 matching colors for red, ex: black, orange, other teint of red, some blue, etc...

I don't have knowledge about how colors and their calculation work, so any help, hints, code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried to do in code?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: You could experiment with http://colorschemedesigner.com/

Comment: @MarkusJarderot you should submit this as an answer. The "color wheel" is how this is usually done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSV is a much better colorspace to manipulate colors in than RGB, because HSV's axes correspond directly to useful transformations of a color.

To make a color brighter or more saturated, increase its saturation. To desaturate (make grayscale), decrease the saturation. Decreasing the V(alue) of a color makes it darker - all colors with V of 0 are black. Changing the hue alters the color itself, moving around a color wheel. See Wikipedia's [article on HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) for more details.

What transformations you do depend on what sort of related colors you want to generate. If you want complementary colors, for instance, you probably want to take the color, leave the S and V unmodified, and generate colors 1/3rd and 2/3rds of the way around the color wheel from the current color. Brighter and darker versions can be made by varying the value, while more and less 'intense' colors can be made by varying the saturation.

Answer (score -2):

RGB colors are just a space in memory where you have three values, each ranging from 0 to 255. Red, for example, is just 255, 0, 0... 255 (maximum) in the "Red" field of the memory location, and zero in the "Blue" and "Green". It's when you mix these different values around that you start to get the almost infinite array of colors we see on our screens.

I can't quite tell you what to do with your code without seeing it, but I can tell you that if you have a control or object where you have a RGB property, you can modify the values in said property to make the color of the control or object any color you want. Experiment to see what values produce the colors you want, then enter these into the property fields in the dynamic manner that you seek.